# Hide table columns by class

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a table from n columns. Each cell has a class `column-n`.

I want to add on table class `hide-column-n` and hide all cells with class `column-n`.
Is this possible do it through css?

Example:

```css
.table {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .table thead{
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
  .table td{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="column-1">One</td>
    <td class="column-2">Two</td>
    <td class="column-3">Three</td>
    <td class="column-x">...</td>
    <td class="column-n">N</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="column-1">One</td>
    <td class="column-2">Two</td>
    <td class="column-3">Three</td>
    <td class="column-x">...</td>
    <td class="column-n">N</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column-1">One</td>
    <td class="column-2">Two</td>
    <td class="column-3">Three</td>
    <td class="column-x">...</td>
    <td class="column-n">N</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You cannot add class `hide-column-n` using CSS but you can hide them based on pattern. For example, you can do `[class='column-10']{display: none;}` or `td:nth-child(10){display: none;}`

Comment: @Harry I add hide-column-n through js, but I can't understand how to write rule on css

Comment: The problem is that in css I don't know n value

Comment: Well, if you are already adding class through JS then why not just add `.hide {display: none}` without the extra stuff. It would become much easier wouldn't it? Your CSS needn't even have to know `n` then because the JS is already adding the `.hide` class to whatever that needs to be hidden.

Comment: Add your code, create a jsfiddle

Comment: For example I have 10 columns and 50 row. To add class for all cells that I need, I should cache 500 cells. Because table is adaptive.

Comment: I think you should clarify the question a bit more. When will the columns need to be hidden? Do you have a pattern based on which the cells need to be hidden (say the last column or every 5th column etc)? If your JS is already adding classes then what is stopping you from adding just a `hide` class to the columns that need to be hidden instead of `hide-column-n`? If you use a common class then you need not know what `n` is at all in CSS (or) are you saying that you want to avoid adding classes with JS and just use CSS? If that is the case, there needs to be a pattern.

Comment: @Harry Thanks. Now I exactly know that in css I should know column count. I was hoping that something like [class='column-'] will help

Comment: @Illorian: [class^='column-'] will help but wouldn't all your columns have a class in that pattern? I mean, my assumption is that your first column will have `column-1`, second will be `column-2` and so on. Is that not the case? Can you post a sample of your HTML?

Comment: @Harry I hope that help

Comment: So, the requirement is to always hide only the cells with `column-n` irrespective of what `n` is right?

Comment: @Harry yes. The point is that I need mode than 1 column when window is resizing

Comment: @Illorian: I am confused seeing this comment - *why nth(2)? If I have 17 columns and I need hide 13-17 column, it's not working*. Are you looking to hide a range of elements and the range can vary dynamically? If yes, then you are better of using JS.

Comment: @Harry of course. Right now I use JS to hide cells. But problem is that I need keep all cell in JS or search them ever time when I need hide them. Maybe you have best way of this problem?

Comment: Nope, I don't think I have a solution to your problem. Since there are way too many dynamic factors, JS would your best bet.

Comment: @Harry How do you think what happen if I would generate css class through JS and put it in a style tag?

Answer (score 1):

Here is example https://jsfiddle.net/xr21kwrh/

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class=column-1">One</th>
      <th class"column-2">Two</th>
      ...
      <th class="column-n">N</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class=column-1">One</t>
      <td class"column-2">Two</td>
      ...
      <td class="column-n">N</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=column-1">One</t>
      <td class"column-2">Two</td>
      ...
      <td class="column-n">N</td>
    </tr>
    ...
 </tbody>
</table>

<style>
th:nth-child(2){display: none;}
td:nth-child(2){display: none;}
</style>
```

Comment: why nth(2)? If I have 17 columns and I need hide 13-17 column, it's not working

Comment: If your n is dynamic value then why don't you hide your column dynamically using DOM...

Comment: Where is your code.. be it php or js you can always follow similar approach to hide things dynamically. In above answer you get that `{display: none;}` need to be used

Comment: JS help to understand when I need hide cells. But now I must get them from table and set class for each table. It's not good. And I want know could css help me?

Comment: suppose you want to hide all columns with name starting with 'xyz' or some other criteria. Here you need to do is `$('td[name^=xyz]').hide` jquery

Comment: Describe your problem clearly. there are many functions like 'remove', 'hide' that can help you achieve it but logic must be clear

Comment: I don't use jquery

Comment: Whatever, but you must have some logic to hide n number of columns... if you present that, people can help you translate that to your program..

What is the logic(basis) to hide n-13 to n-17 for example

Comment: Window resizing, columns hiding. It's already working on JS. But as I said, I keep in memory all cells

Comment: I know that, but what is the basis on which you want to hide your columns..
If you say you want to hide 13 to 17 then you say you want to hide 20-25. there must be some logic behind this.

Comment: Do you want to hide last 4 columns or you want to show 10 columns and hide rest...? Unless there is some logic how can one help you.

Comment: Yes. I calculate container width and table width and know when I should hide table.  The question is about how could I do it with css and is possible it?

Comment: Bu the way I couldn't use @media

Comment: offcourse it is possible... you need to show us your code to so that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <table class="table">
         <thead>
         <tr>
      <th class=column-1">One</th>
      <th class"column-2">Two</th>
      ...
      <th class="column-n">N</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class=column-1">One</t>
      <td class"column-2">Two</td>
      ...
      <td class="column-n">N</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=column-1">One</t>
      <td class"column-2">Two</td>
      ...
      <td class="column-n">N</td>
    </tr>
    ...
 </tbody>
</table>

<style>
.column-n{ display-none !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: n is a dynamic value

Comment: so add these styles dynamically too, like: ".column-1", ".column-n", ".column-whatever"...

Answer (score 0):

If you use sass/scss you can do so (in SCSS):

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .hide-column-#{$i} .column-#{$i} {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

it will compile to:

```
.hide-column-1 .column-1 {
  display: none;
}

.hide-column-2 .column-2 {
  display: none;
}

....

.hide-column-n .column-n {
  display: none;
}
```

then use it like expected:

```
<table class="table hide-column-1 hide-column-2">
```

[codepen demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNEOZB?editors=1100)

Comment: Yes but problem is that I don't know columns count. Best solution to call it a plugin

Comment: but you can set some max count. like in Bootstrap Grid system - col-1, col-2 ... col-12 (max)